# Use OCR on a file located in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I performed a few tests with OCR using image upload but would like to use OCR with remote images. These images are located in Google storage and yet I have the following error:

```
image-annotator::error(10): Can not open file: gs://my_sample_api.appspot.com/my_sample_image.jpg
```

Here is the documentation related: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-fulltext

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related to Firebase free plan limitation, difficult to find however since no log was provided...